# Unit test failed with moto in azure pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, amazon-cloudwatch, moto

I made a wrapper for aws cloudwatch in python with boto3.

And I am doing the unit test with *moto*, everything go smoothly in my local PC.

After I pushed my code to Azure Repo to trigger the pipeline, I always get the error message.

I want to know how is the compatibility of Azure pipeline to run the 'moto' library.

Comment: Can you post the error message that you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for few days I found the problem finally.
I have to **scale my searched day to contain my logs timestamp**
It means my timestamp of metrics is datetime.today(), and I need to set the Metric Data Queries start date and end date parameter to datetime.today() -(+) timedelta(1) to scale the query date, I don't really know why it work without the scaling in local PC.